# Find the count of raw ingredients using Recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

We are given a dictionary of recipes, as well as list of raw ingredients;

```
recipes = {
'axe': {'stick': 1, 'rock': 1, 'tape': 1},
'double_axe': {'axe': 2, 'tape': 1},
'quadruple_axe': {'double_axe': 2, 'tape': 1, 'rock': 2}
}

raw_ingredients = {'rock', 'stick', 'tape'}
```

The question is; programmatically find number of raw ingredients(of each type) used for each recipe. Please note that raw ingredients only include `rock`,`tape`, and `stick`.

Here is my attempt to solve this question in Python;

```
def get_ingredients(name, s, l):
s[name]=dict1
#get dictionary for each recipe

k=dict1.keys()
#retrieve the keys
dict2={}
#define empty dictionary to store count of raw ingredients
for i in k:
 #loop over the keys   
    if i in l:
 #if key is a raw ingredient, we will increase the count for that corresponding raw ingredient
        dict2[i]=dict1[i]
    else:
#otherwise call the function recursively
        for j in range(0,dict1[i]):
        get_ingredients(i, s, l)
```

Here `name` can be either `{axe, double_axe,quadruple_axe}`, `s` is same as `recipes`, and `l` is same as `raw_ingredients`.

I fully understand that, my code is not complete. It is only my first attempt at the question, and I am trying to get skeleton here. Here are the two key questions I need help with;

1. First, how to keep track of count of the ingredients needed, for instance `quadruple_axe` needs 4 sticks in total.
2. Second, when do we stop recursing, i.e. what is the base case here?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Please don't annotate "same as" variables and expect us to translate with every line we read.  Instead, give your variables clear, meaningful names.

Comment: It looks like the indentation of your code is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, how to keep track of count of the ingredients needed, for
>   instance quadruple_axe needs 4 sticks in total.

Your instinct to use a dictionary to gather the ingredient counts is good:

```
dict2={}
#define empty dictionary to store count of raw ingredients
```

But please, put the comment *before* the line about which it comments, not after.

> Second, when do we stop recursing, i.e. what is the base case here?

You handle raw ingredients directly, you recurse on sub recipes.  So the recusion naturally stops when you've exhausted all the sub recipes -- you don't have to test for it explicitly.

I recommend that you stop thinking in terms of `dict1` and `dict2` as well as `i`, `j` and `k` and program in the language of the problem.  I also suggest that you use a `defaultdict` to collect your final list of raw ingredients, converting it to a generic `dict` at the end if you feel the need.  But this is optional and just simplifies the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

recipes = {
    'axe': {'stick': 1, 'rock': 1, 'tape': 1},
    'double_axe': {'axe': 2, 'tape': 1},
    'quadruple_axe': {'double_axe': 2, 'tape': 1, 'rock': 2}
}

raw_ingredients = {'rock', 'stick', 'tape'}

def count_raw_ingredients(recipe):
    ingredients = defaultdict(int)

    for ingredient, amount in recipes[recipe].items():
        if ingredient in raw_ingredients:
            ingredients[ingredient] += amount
        else:
            for subingredient, subamount in count_raw_ingredients(ingredient).items():
                ingredients[subingredient] += amount * subamount

    return dict(ingredients)

print(count_raw_ingredients('quadruple_axe'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
{'stick': 4, 'rock': 6, 'tape': 7}
>
```

Comment: @cdlane.Thanks for your response. I just have one question; in the line `ingredients[subingredient] += amount * subamount`, do we really need to do an in-place increase. If we do an in-place increase, it might happen that no. of sticks for double axe can reach to (1+(2*1))=3. So, won't it be better to do a simple replacement, `ingredients[subingredient] = amount * subamount`. Can you kindly clarify why do we need to do an in-place increase here?thanks

Comment: @jayant, you could always try it and see but my belief is it will eventually lead to the wrong answer.  The raw ingredients you get by looking at sub recipes are independent of raw ingredients listed in the current recipe so we always need to be adding.

Answer (score 0):

Your base case is when the ingredient name does not appear as a recipe label.
You recur on the three `axe` types; you stop on `stick`, `rock`, or `tape`.

You can keep track by passing back a dict of base ingredient counts.  For instance, a check for "double-axe" will return the computational roll-up for `2 * {'stick': 1, 'rock': 1, 'tape': 1} + {'tape': 1}`.  You should be able to derive that code for yourself, or look it up here with something like "Python add values two dicts".